# Everything Should Be Different

Tags: discussion, fun

I feel strongly that the current SO website would be much more effective if it was completely different than how it is now.

Problems include:

- Closing eyes or adjusting monitor orientation causes site to disappear from view.
- No useful information about paint.
- Everything should be different.

Instead of asking, answering and voting on questions related to programming, people may find it more valuable to have access to a website about paint, or perhaps a website featuring a variety of [serious news articles](http://www.theonion.com).

What do others think?  How should reputation be calculated for the paint website?  Should it allow questions?

Comment: Bookmarking this even though I disagree, because it deftly captures the essence of *so many* feature requests here on Meta.

Comment: I'm glad some people can appreciate it.  I think it's healthy to laugh at ourselves from time to time.

Comment: The paint site should not allow questions, only answers, to focus it on the *relevant* content.

Comment: Reputation should be directly proportional to the frequency with which a user utilizes the color brown on the paint website.  It's simple, and it's accurate.

Comment: I like how voting to close this question was a very good predictor of who would become future moderators

Comment: @RichardTingle: "But I'm sure they're fun people in real life."